# How to get DOM from debugging tab to extension script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a bit of help here as the examples I've seen have only been from the tab to the extension and not the other way around.

I'm looking to grab the source code of a page/tab that I am debugging with a custom Chrome Extension. I want the extension to call a message and the response to be sent back to the extension panel javascript making the call.

**Manifest**

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "<all_urls>",
  "debugger"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId:chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tabs) {
    debuggee = {tabId:tabs[0].id};
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggee, version, onAttach.bind(null, tabs[0].id));
  });
});

function onAttach(tabId) {
  chrome.windows.create({url: "spy.html?" + tabId, type: "panel", width: 900, height: 700}, function(window) {
    winId = window.id;
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.data == "getHTML") {
      sendResponse({data: document.getElementById('header').innerHTML});
  }
});
```

**spy.html**

```
<script src="spy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**spy.js**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:tabId}, "DOM.getDocument");
  chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
});

function onEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {    
  if (message=="DOM.documentUpdated") {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {data: "getHTML"}, function(response) {console.log(response.data);});
  }
```

**Result**

Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:235
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:235

> Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'data' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>       at chrome-extension://fpdkndicjblnkakkiiapbbdflkehjmgm/headers.js:132:91
>       at miscellaneous_bindings:279:11
>       at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
>       at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:393:17)
>       at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect (miscellaneous_bindings:238:27)

I get this error when I try to run it. What am I missing?

Comment: Where's the background.js?

Comment: I've updated the initial post. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @ilya: `windows.getCurrent` and `tabs.getSelected` are deprecated and `chrome.debugger.attach` has only two arguments

Comment: @Sudarshan so should I just rework the flow to match your answer. i.e remove the "background" in the manifest and add the popup.html to the browser action? I have other code in the background.js, mostly listeners. 1) chrome.windows.onRemoved -> Detach debugger 2) chrome.debugger.onDetach -> Remove popup window

Comment: @Sudarshan BTW you can specify a callback for the attach - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html#method-attach

Comment: @ilya: I over looked on debugger part, if your users are ready to take this change you can do it else you can get your flow working with some changes..

Comment: This will be an extension used by my company for internal debugging. I'm not looking to be cautious on the permission side so much as to get this working. Any suggestions would be helpful. I've looked into keeping a port open, but I get the same message even though the port names are the same.

Comment: @ilya: After eliminating deprecated functions and all , can you post your updated code(relevant parts), i can pick it up from there

Comment: @Sudarshan I have updated the post accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ilya: How do you get `tabId` of `chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:tabId},` in `spy.js`?

Comment: @Sudarshan var tabId=parseInt(window.location.search.substring(1));

Comment: @ilya: You issue is fixed, check my edit of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've figured it out.
Since I need the DOM of the loaded page, I'm going to use the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener in my background page to send the code when the page is loaded. This way I don't have to depend on the 2 way communication between the tab and extension.

**Manifest**

Removed content.js

**background.js**

Added the following

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tabId != _tabId) {return;}
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:"var x = document.documentElement.innerHTML;x"}, function (r) {
      chrome.extension.sendMessage(null, {"data": r[0]});       
    });
  }
});
```

**content.js**

REMOVED

**spy.js**

Added the following

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  console.log("Request.data: " + request.data);
});
```

Comment: Changing the title to help others

Answer (score 1):

How are you capturing `tabId` of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId,`, can you post your full script to debug problem,if you are looking for a sample code for passing message from `Chrome Extension` to `Debugging Tab` check this.

## References

- [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)
- [tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)
- [tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)
- [extension.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage)

#### manifest.json

Registered `popup` page and `content scripts`.

```
{
 "name": "Pass message from Chrome Extension to Debugging Tab",
 "version": "1",
 "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205155/how-can-i-pass-a-message-from-my-chrome-extension-to-debugging-tab",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["selection.js"]
  }
 ],
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### popup.html

Ensured HTML Adheres to CSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                width: 300px;
            }
            textarea {
                width: 250px;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
          <button id="submit">Pass Message</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### popup.js

Pass Message to Content Scripts.

```
function passMessage() {
    //Select current tab to send message
  chrome.tabs.query({"active":true,"currentWindow":true,"status":"complete","windowType":"normal"}, function(tabs) {
  //It returns array so looping over tabs result
    for(tab in tabs){

    //Send Message to a tab
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[tab].id, {method: "Hi Content Script"});
    }   
});
}


// Bind On click event to passMessage() function
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function (){

    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = passMessage;
});
```

#### selection.js

Added a handler to catch messages sent from popup page

```
 //Add a handler to handle message sent from popup.html
 chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    console.log("Message "+request+" is recieved");

});
```

## EDIT:

I got your code working after eliminates some deprecated API() like `sendResponse`

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    version = "1.0";
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
    }, function (tabs) {
        debuggee = {
            tabId: tabs[0].id
        };
        chrome.debugger.attach(debuggee, version, onAttach.bind(null, tabs[0].id));
    });
});

function onAttach(tabId) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "spy.html?" + tabId,
        type: "panel",
        width: 900,
        height: 700
    }, function (window) {
        winId = window.id;
    });
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
    console.log("Message recieved");
    if (request.data == "getHTML") {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({
            "data": "Some Stuff"
        });
    }
});
```

**spy.js**

```
tabId = parseInt(window.location.search.substring(1));
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        tabId: tabId
    }, "DOM.getDocument");
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
});

function onEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {
    if (message == "DOM.documentUpdated") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            "data": "getHTML"
        });
    }
}
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

How ever ensure you do not trigger developer tools manually during testing.

Comment: TabId is set by the background.js file that is attaching the debugger and opening the popup. 

I'll add the code to the original post.
I tried just changing the manifest to include the "<all_urls>", but the rest seems to fit the same. The only other difference is that you are loading the popup as a browser action, while I'm using the background.js to load the popup.

Comment: @ilya: You are **not** loading popup you are creating a new window of type panel, how ever you can bind your debugger session after creating a new panel

Comment: That is correct. I have changed the terminology since I tried your method and i DON'T want a default popup for the extension, but rather a new frame to display the results.

Comment: I was able to implement what you corrected, but this doesn't work as expected. The chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"data": "getHTML"}); does not get called within the function... or if it does there is nothing listening. When the page is finally done loading, i can manually send the message via console and only then do I get something back. Any ideas why this isn't happening? Is there a different tOt value to find out when the DOM has been fully loaded than Dom.documentUpdated?

Comment: @ilya: Can you explain what is not working as per expectations?, i tested this and i was able to trace debugger events; What is you want to track?

Comment: So by desired workflow, once the extension is clicked, the tab needs to be reloaded for the extension to start watching. Once that happens I send the DOM.getDocument command to wait for the DOM.documentUpdated message. At that point the code is supposed to fire the chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"data": "getHTML"}); and get back the response from the context.js. It does not happen. Only if I open the console window of the extension and run that sendMessage command, do i then get back a response. Hope that makes sense.